# How to add the total sums to the table and get proportion for each cell in R

Tags: r, margin, contingency

I'm trying to get a proportion for each cell by dividing each row by the row sum, but R gives me an Error saying,

> Error in data.table$Country : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

How can I fix this? Also, how can add total sum values for the entire columns and rows to data.table? I get this values when I run `addmargins(data.table)`, but I'd like to attach the sums to my dataframe.

---

Here's my code:

```
x = c(40,50,30,30,50)                
y = c(40,20,30,40,45)                              
data.table = rbind(x,y)   
data.table
dimnames(data.table)=list("Country"=c("England","Germany"),"Score"=c("Q-Score","T-score","X-score","Y-score","Z-score"))
addmargins(data.table)
table(data.table$Country,data.table$Score/rowSums(table(data.table&Country,data.table$Score)))
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you create a data.frame.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The output of a call to `table` is an object of class `table`. This is basically an `array`. You cannot use `$` to reference arrays or atomic vectors. (Hence the error).

If you want to assign the results of `addmargins(data.table)` to an object, then you are more than free to do so

```
margin_table <- addmargins(data.table)
```

It looks like you want to then create a table of the relative proportions.

`prop.table` is useful for this.

```
 prop.table(margin_table)

         Score
Country      Q-Score    T-score X-score    Y-score    Z-score       Sum
  England 0.02666667 0.03333333    0.02 0.02000000 0.03333333 0.1333333
  Germany 0.02666667 0.01333333    0.02 0.02666667 0.03000000 0.1166667
  Sum     0.05333333 0.04666667    0.04 0.04666667 0.06333333 0.2500000
```

you could also run `prop.table` on the original to get the row proportions (1 = rows, 2 = columns)

```
 prop.table(data.table, margins = 1)
      Score
Country     Q-Score   T-score   X-score   Y-score   Z-score
  England 0.2000000 0.2500000 0.1500000 0.1500000 0.2500000
  Germany 0.2285714 0.1142857 0.1714286 0.2285714 0.2571429
```

The help file  for `table` (accessed by `?table` or `help('table')` is detailed and contains links to  the help files for `prop.table` and `addmargins`!

Comment: thanks for the help on adding margins! actually I wasn't trying to get the relative proportions. I'm trying to divide the row for England by it's rowsum and divide the German row by its rowsum. could you show me how to do this using this table? or should I make a different data?

Comment: See my edit. Read the help files! If what you are doing is a standard thing to do, there will almost certainly be a function in a package for it.